# How to return deepest directory name and file name for each file using walk function?

Tags: python

I've written a function, which returns the absolute path of files after the traverse searching.

But how to return only last folder name and file name for each file (in conjunction) ?

For example, I have 3 files:

- "D:\python\demo_project\dir1\dir2\dir3\file1.sql"
- "D:\python\demo_project\dir1\dir2\file2.sql"
- "D:\python\demo_project\dir1\file3.sql"

The results should be:

- dir3\file1.sql
- dir2\file2.sql
- dir1\file3.sql

```py
def find_sql(main_dir):
    arr = []
    for dirpath, subdirs, files in walk(main_dir):
        arr.extend(path.join(dirpath, x) for x in files if x.endswith(".sql"))

    return arr

call_find_sql = find_sql("D:\\python\\demo_project")
```

Comment: But, more seriously, I don't think I understand the question. What ordering do we need here for "last"?

Comment: I think I must be missing something, but if you want the last folder/filename pair, is that not in `arr[-1]` after the loop completes? That does rather depend on what you mean by *last*.

Comment: @roganjosh Please take a look on updated description

Comment: You've basically done it if you're happy with the ordering, but you haven't assigned the returned value to a name. `new_value = find_sql("D:\\python\\demo_project")` maybe

Comment: if you want the deepest nested .sql : sort the result with `key=len` - use the last result [-1] (aka the longest name found). You can then split it by `/` to get subdirs and names as you like. What is your real problem?

Comment: ... now you return something but do nothing with it ...

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details as per the How to Create a [mcve] page. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.path.basename` on `dirpath`.

For example it will convert `'D:\\python\\demo_project\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3'` to `'dir3'`.

```
from os import walk, path

def find_sql(main_dir):
    arr = []
    for dirpath, subdirs, files in walk(main_dir):
        arr.extend(
            path.join(path.basename(dirpath), x)
            for x in files
            if x.endswith(".sql")
            )
    return arr
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution! This is exactly what I needed.